# javascript fonts

Tags: javascript, fonts

OK so I want to use FixedSystem as a font on a web page.. I COULD use Cufon but I want people to be able to select the text as in mouseover it and copy it.

Anyone have anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use fontsquirrel's @font-face service to encode cross-compatible web fonts and generate the CSS.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

But, it looks like their site is down right now.   [The Essential Guide to @font-face](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/) offers some other solutions and insight.

Comment: +1, font squirrel is good stuff. Looks like their site is down right now, though :(

Answer (score -1):

use lobster if you have it on whatever youre using
its nice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33398417)